# Solved the problem using the echolan form. However, I am currently struggling to find the variables associated with this solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistical-inference

The matrix is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 4 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\  
 1 & 2 & -3 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & -5 & 7 & -5 & -1 \\
 7 & -4 & 5 & -4 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
R1(-1/4)+R2
R1(-1/2)+R3
R1(-1/4)(7)+R4
(1/2)R3+R2
changed R3 whit R4

Solved the system of linear equations by transforming the matrix to gaussian form and I have reached the desired form and the last two rows of the matrix are zero.
I am currently struggling to find the values of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$. The question specifically asks for the value of S(Ω) and I am unsure how to proceed with calculating it.:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 4 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
 0 &\dfrac34 & -\dfrac{13}4 & \dfrac34 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the pivot method of Gauss  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fD79MlN_ILc
you will have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}4&-1&1&-1&3\\ 1&2&-3&2&2\\ 2&-5&7&-5&-1\\ 7&-4&5&-4&4\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}4&-1&1&-1&3\\ 0&\frac{9}{4}&-\frac{13}{4}&\frac{9}{4}&\frac{5}{4}\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$